# Uncaught ReferenceError: GIF is not defined with gif.js

Tags: javascript, gif, p5.js

(Hey I am trying to use the gif.js together with p5.js in the Processing Launcher.

I have trouble getting gif.js to work in the first place because I get the **Uncaught ReferenceError: GIF is not defined**
so I am wondering if I have added the Library correctly. I downloaded them from Github and used them like this:

```
<!-- PLEASE NO CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE (UNTIL I SAY SO) -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="createGif.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="myShader.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Larrytarium.js"></script>
  <!-- OK, YOU CAN MAKE CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE AGAIN -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/gif.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/gif.worker.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/ready.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/mootools.js"></script>
```

I am sorry but as being kinda new to all of this, I cannot really work with the minimal Information given on the [official GitHub](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js).

This is my current code (createGif.js) where the Error persists, whatever I do:

```
var CanvasElement = this.p5Canvas

var gif = new GIF({
  workers: 2,
  quality: 10
});

// add a canvas element
gif.addFrame(CanvasElement, {delay: 200});

gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});

gif.render();
```

Maybe it is just something so stupid I cannot see it after looking at it for hours :D
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
To further explain:
I have two main .js files with one being the p5.js File which includes all the animation and Canvas stuff and the other one is the one for gif.js which content is posted above.
The HTML is empty otherwise the imports, like Processing generates it.

Comment: Did you put your script AFTER all the p5/gif scripts?

Comment: Do you mean the one above? It is separated in another js file

Comment: Side note: Don't use the `language` attribute on the `<script>` tag. [It is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#deprecated_attributes).

Comment: Yeah, separated is good but what I mean is, did you order it properly?

Comment: @TypeBeta Where did you include the "separate JS file"? Before the p5/gif.js scripts or after?

Comment: @Ivar thanks for the heads up, that was auto generated by Processing so I kept it

Comment: I edit the Code box above in a sec. Processing reedits the Imports above the line itself so createGif.js is called earlier than the gif.js Library. That is the problem you are referring to right?

Comment: Maybe to add to it:
I also tried to have that code in the html instead of having it in a seperate file, but same issue

Comment: @TypeBeta That's indeed the problem. By default the `<script>` tags will evaluate the script before continuing to the next one, so at that point `GIF` is indeed not defined because the JS file loading in this library hasn't run yet.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks. I think I got that step to work as the Error now changed to  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'width')** 
So now I think I have to find out how to reference the p5Canvas correctly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the Comments, it seems to be a problem with the  tags.
Although I did not yet rearrange them, deleting the **language** tag seemed to work.